# dplyr - creating new column with field set from column name

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a rather messy data frame with column names something like 
`colnames(df) <- c("X1", "X2", "X3", "Y1", "Y2", "Y3")`  
And I want to pivot longer to create a dataframe with three columns instead, using `pivot_longer`, where there is a column each for X and Y, and a third column (called "run") which contains 1,2 or 3 depending on the column name above.
`Pivot_longer` seems like the function to use, but I'm not sure how to use it to dynamically create 2 columns called X and Y, taken from the column name, and draw the value for the third column from the column name also.
Would anyone know how to do this? It's worth noting that the actual df has many different column names, so brute forcing the naming of the new columns wouldn't be possible.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Pivot longer would give you key, value.  You can then mutate the key to add a new run column, rename the key X or Y, and then pivot longer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pivot_longer` specifying the regex in `names_pattern`.

```
df <- data.frame(X1 = rnorm(5), X2 = rnorm(5), Y1 = rnorm(5), Y2 = rnorm(5))

tidyr::pivot_longer(df, 
                    everything(), 
                    names_to = c('.value', 'run'), 
                    names_pattern = '([A-Z])(\\d+)')

#   run        X       Y
#   <chr>    <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 1      0.376   -1.73  
# 2 2     -0.497    1.24  
# 3 1      0.310   -2.20  
# 4 2      0.0114   0.783 
# 5 1      0.00501  0.543 
# 6 2      0.00986  0.0481
# 7 1     -0.0376   0.0214
# 8 2      0.678   -1.48  
# 9 1      0.724    0.163 
#10 2      1.03     0.436
```

Comment: Hi @Ronak, this worked perfectly for me, thanks so much for your answer. For anyone else stuck, `pivot_longer` also takes the argument `pivot_longer(df, !(col))` where col is a column you don't want to pivot - I found that useful as I needed to keep another column un-pivoted.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is `names_sep`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = c(".value", "run"),
          names_sep = "(?<=[A-Z])(?=\\d)")



# A tibble: 10 x 3
#   run        X      Y
#   <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 1      0.654  1.58 
# 2 2     -0.115 -0.858
# 3 1     -0.162  0.581
# 4 2      0.667  0.242
# 5 1      0.905 -0.385
# 6 2     -0.787  1.01 
# 7 1     -1.68   0.171
# 8 2      0.264  0.420
# 9 1     -0.131 -0.405
#10 2     -1.15  -0.417
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(X1 = rnorm(5), X2 = rnorm(5), Y1 = rnorm(5), Y2 = rnorm(5))
```